# Active Directory Administrative Center doesn't list users?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I opened "Active Directory Administrative Center" on our domain controller and when I add the criteria "Users with disabled/enabled accounts." it returns nothing, but I know we have users accounts listed in active directory.

Comment: what happens when you do the following "dsquery user DC=yourdomain,DC=Com -o upn -name jon* -disabled " obviously with your domain info etc..

Comment: I have to say that ADAC is not a very intuitive tool. I couldn't figure out how to list users using that criteria either.

Comment: somewhat doesn't make sense to list accounts that are disabled and enabled, in this case it should show all users.

Comment: Tony, If it's a Boolean "and", then it should properly return 0 accounts. If it was an "or", then it would return all accounts.

Comment: yep I was bass ackwards on this..

Comment: What part of that is an AND and what part of that is an OR?   The ',''s?

Comment: this all seems kinda stupid what are you looking for, disabled accounts? if so like mfinni said select disabled accounts...

Comment: I'm looking for users with enabled or disabled.

Comment: Lee - clarify your criteria. The set of all users will be strictly composed of users enabled, and users disabled, with no overlap between the two subsets.

Comment: @leeand00 so a list of users enabled OR disabled will be blank and quite useless...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - selecting that query brings up the condition, and you have to select if you meant "enabled" or "disabled". Make sure that the Scope is appropriate. Hit the "Search" button. Came right up for me.